# Unable to get ArgoCD working on EC2 running centos 7

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubernetes-pod, argocd

I am trying to run `argocd` on my EC2 instance running `centos 7` by following [official documentation](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/getting_started/) and [EKS workshop from AWS](https://www.eksworkshop.com/intermediate/290_argocd/install/), but it is in pending state, all pods from `kube-system` namespace are running fine.

below is the output of `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
argocd        argocd-application-controller-5785f6b79-nvg7n                     0/1     Pending   0          29s
argocd        argocd-dex-server-7f5d7d6645-gprpd                                0/1     Pending   0          19h
argocd        argocd-redis-cccbb8f7-vb44n                                       0/1     Pending   0          19h
argocd        argocd-repo-server-67ddb49495-pnw5k                               0/1     Pending   0          19h
argocd        argocd-server-6bcbf7997d-jqqrw                                    0/1     Pending   0          19h
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-56b44cd6d5-tzgdm                          1/1     Running   0          19h
kube-system   calico-node-4z9tx                                                 1/1     Running   0          19h
kube-system   coredns-f9fd979d6-8d6hm                                           1/1     Running   0          19h
kube-system   coredns-f9fd979d6-p9dq6                                           1/1     Running   0          19h
kube-system   etcd-ip-10-1-3-94.us-east-2.compute.internal                      1/1     Running   0          19h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-ip-10-1-3-94.us-east-2.compute.internal            1/1     Running   0          19h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-ip-10-1-3-94.us-east-2.compute.internal   1/1     Running   0          19h
kube-system   kube-proxy-tkp7k                                                  1/1     Running   0          19h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-ip-10-1-3-94.us-east-2.compute.internal            1/1     Running   0          19h
```

While same configuration is working fine on my local mac, I've made sure that `docker`, `kubernetes` services are up and runnning. Tried deleting pods, reconfigured argocd, however everytime result remained same.

Being new to `ArgoCD` I am unable to figure out the reason for the same. Please let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Having the pods in `pending` is usually a scheduling problem. Not enough CPU/RAM available to fulfill the requests, any taints on the nodes that prevent the scheduling or maybe some pv/pvc constraints? Do you see anything in the logs from the kubelet?

Comment: Got taint problem when explored describe pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was by running:

```
kubectl describe pods <name>  -n argocd
```

It gave output ending with FailedScheduling:

```
...
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  3m (x5 over 7m2s)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

henceforth, by referring [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/calebhailey/homelab/issues/3), I figured out to run:

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

After this command, pods started to work and transitioned from `Pending` state to `Running` with `kubectl describe pods` showing output as:

```
...
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  3m (x5 over 7m2s)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
  Normal   Scheduled         106s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned argocd/argocd-server-7d44dfbcc4-qfj6m to ip-XX-XX-XX-XX.<region>.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulling           105s               kubelet            Pulling image "argoproj/argocd:v1.7.6"
  Normal   Pulled            81s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "argoproj/argocd:v1.7.6" in 23.779457251s
  Normal   Created           72s                kubelet            Created container argocd-server
  Normal   Started           72s                kubelet            Started container argocd-server
```

From this error and resolution I've learned to always use `kubectl describe pods` to resolve the errors.